# Colouring points in an ordination plot in r using a data frame

Tags: r, text, label

Using the following data.frame:

```
df<-data.frame("sites"=as.character(1:20),"type"=c(rep("small",10),rep("large",10)))

   sites  type
1      1 small
2      2 small
3      3 small
4      4 small
5      5 small
6      6 small
7      7 small
8      8 small
9      9 small
10    10 small
11    11 large
12    12 large
13    13 large
14    14 large
15    15 large
16    16 large
17    17 large
18    18 large
19    19 large
20    20 large
```

I would like to colour the text labels (i.e. 1-20) by label (i.e. "small", "large") in the following ordination plot:

```
library(vegan)
library(stats)

data(dune)
dist <- vegdist(wisconsin(dune))

#Ordinate data
pc<-cmdscale(dist, k=10, eig=TRUE, add=TRUE, x.ret =TRUE)   

#Create ordination plot     
quartz(title="PCoA on coral data")
fig<-ordiplot(scores(pc)[,c(1,2)], type="t", main="PCoA")
```

[image]

Comment: please specify what packages you are using

Comment: I just added this to the question. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the text label color is hard coded in ordiplot so you have to set up the plot and then use text() to plot the labels by group:

```
score <- scores(pc)[, 1:2]
fig<-ordiplot(score, type="n", main="PCoA")
color <- c("red", "blue")
sz <- as.numeric(df$type[as.numeric(rownames(score))])
text(score, rownames(score), col=color[sz])
```

Comment: Indeed, if one reads the documentation for `?ordiplot` they _recommend_ using `type = "none"` and then adding points and text separately for precisely this reason.